# Android: sliding drawer content overlapping the whole screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment, slide

I have an application that uses a sliding drawer. I had to make some changes, the sliding drawer content was a simple relative layout but I had to change it to include a fragment.

this is the slider layout before the changes:

```
<SlidingDrawer
             android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:handle="@+id/handle"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:content="@+id/content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@id/handle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/handle"
                android:rotation="180"
                 />

             <RelativeLayout
                 android:id="@id/content"
                 android:background="@drawable/border"
                 android:layout_width="140dip"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:orientation="vertical"
                 android:rotation="180"
                 android:focusable="true"
                 android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                 <EditText
                     android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="50dp"
                     android:id="@+id/editInp"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                     android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                     android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                     android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
                     android:hint=""
                     android:textColor="@color/themeapp"
                     android:background="@drawable/layout_corner_white"
                     android:singleLine="true"
                     android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"/>

                 <ImageView
                     android:id="@+id/clear_button"
                     android:layout_width="35dp"
                     android:layout_height="35dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="23dip"
                     android:layout_alignRight="@id/editInp"
                     android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"/>

                 <RelativeLayout
                     android:id="@+id/progress_conteiner"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_above="@+id/footer1"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/header1"
                     android:visibility="gone">

                     <ProgressBar

                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                         style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"/>
                 </RelativeLayout>

                 <ExpandableListView
                     android:id="@+id/list"
                     android:layout_below="@+id/editInp"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:paddingTop="20dip"
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                     android:divider="@color/themeapp"
                     android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                     android:indicatorRight="300dp" />
             </RelativeLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

after the changes it looks like this:

```
<SlidingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:handle="@id/handle"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:content="@id/content_frame">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/handle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/handle"
                android:rotation="180"
                 />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            </FrameLayout>

</SlidingDrawer>
```

java code to inflate the fragment:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentFleetListMap(this)).commit();
```

the previous slider content, has been moved (unchanged) to a separate layout file to be used in the newly created fragment.

before, the slider worked weel, but now I see the fragment content overlapped to the activity content (see screeenshot below), is also not limited to the slider space but takes up the whole screen

as you can see in the screenshot the slider is open and it takes the correct portion on the screen (see the position of the handler [the little orange rectangle in the middle of the right side), so I think the problem is actually that the fragment content is not being positioned inside the slider

can anybody help me with this?

[image: see screeenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like this line:

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentFleetListMap(this)).commit();
```

was "adding" my fragment containing the list over the mapfragment instead of the frameLayout. changing it to:

```
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentFleetListMap(this)).commit();
```

solved the problem